# kubernetes - how to mount a directory on a specific node to each pod?

Tags: kubernetes, file-sharing

I have a 3 node test cluster: 1 head and 2 worker nodes (all raspberry pies). I would like to expose a specific folder on the head for read/write on each pod on the cluster (irregardless of which node they are running on).

E.g. my head node has this folder: `/media/usb/test`. I want to mount this to my pods' filesystem to the `mnt/test` directory. Is it possible?

My pods are deployed with this config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 5
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: rpi.home:5000/test
```

Comment: If the USB drive is only mounted on one node, how would the file content get to other nodes?

Comment: That's precisely the question. Someone recommended nfs volumes yesterday, I don't understand why the answer was deleted.

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't solve that problem for you on its own.  Does this have to be "a volume", or can you use other approaches like embedding the content in the images you're running?  (Don't forget that Stack Overflow is specifically about programming questions, and "how do I configure my cluster" or "how do I set up NFS" aren't on-topic.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `hostPath`. More in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath).
It is also recommended not to use it.

> HostPath volumes present many security risks, and it is a best practice to avoid the use of HostPaths when possible. When a HostPath volume must be used, it should be scoped to only the required file or directory, and mounted as ReadOnly.